# MAAS not working

Tags: cloud, maas

I'm trying a whole week to make MASS to work, but no results.

This is the procedure:

```
maas createsuperuser
sudo apt-get install maas-dhcp
maas-import-isos
apt-get install maas-enlist tftpd-hpa
maas-import-isos
```

After this I start node machine with PXE as default first boot device, and select option maas-enlist.
Sistem start to installing some things, and after that on **MAAS WebUI** stand 1 node. But when I click on Node button on WebUI or refresh page, it show 0 node.

Command cobbler system list showing:

```
root@maas-serv:~# cobbler system list
   default
   node-3ee116ea-a8b2-11e1-a735-50e549e38206
```

Also, sometime this procedure register one node, but when registering second one, same problem like I described up.

root@maas-serv:/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg# is empty, only default is there.

On command maas-import-isos there is a one warning.
ftpboot/images/precise-x86_64-maas-ephemeral/initrd
copying images
generating GPXE/PXE configuration files
generating PXE menu structure
warning: kernel option length exceeds 255
warning: kernel option length exceeds 255
warning: kernel option length exceeds 255
warning: kernel option length exceeds 255
copying files for distro: precise-x86_64

Answer (score 2):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1003476/
Hi, a few things you should check:

- sadly, if your nodes have a bad clock, they will fail to register ([bug 978127](http://pad.lv/978127))
- you may need to add the following to `/etc/maas/maas_local_settings.py`

  PSERV_TIMEOUT = 30

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you check your network setting and maas config.

Use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) step by step first and then post your results.

Are you trying to install it on virtual machines?
What's the versions of Ubuntu/MaaS?, the nodes type? can you give us the full details?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this guide to explain step-by-step all operations to make to install and using MaaS on Virtual Environment:

http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-server-edition-part-1

http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-server-edition-part-2

[http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-server-edition-part-3](http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-server-edition-part-2)

[http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-server-edition-part-4](http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/ubuntu-server-how-to-install-metal-as-a-server-maas-cloud-infrastructure-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-server-edition-part-4)

I've installed MaaS on Virtual Environment with kvm and virt-manager.